# Where can I find colleges around Tallahassee, Florida that offer math courses that qualifies someone to teach college level math classes?

Tags: education

Are there any colleges around Tallahassee, Florida where I can take 1 or 2 math classes to teach math on the college level?  I applied to teach full-time at the community college in Tallahassee but they said that 1 or 2 of my master level math classes were not defined correctly.  I need to take about two more to qualify to teach on the college level.  Any advice?
Tamara
Tallahassee, Fl.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! The "obvious suggestion" would be FSU, but maybe this question would be a better fit on [acedemia](http://academia.stackexchange.com/)?